# Как мне после каждой запятой вставить тег </br> php?

Tags: php, массивы

```
let str ="Бананка Duo-5000296:_189гр*1шт=189гр ,Бананка Duo-5000294:_189гр*1шт=189гр ,Рюкзак Urban-5000290:_519гр*1шт=519гр ,Рюкзак Urban-5000289:_519гр*1шт=519гр ,Рюкзак Urban-5000287:_519гр*3шт=1557гр ,Рюкзак Urban-5000286:_519гр*3шт=1557гр ,Рюкзак Gum-5000284:_549гр*3шт=1647гр ,Бананка Town-5000280:_189гр*2шт=378гр ,Итого: 6555гр";
```

Answer (score 3):

С помощью str_replace():

```
$str = "Бананка Duo-5000296:_189гр*1шт=189гр ,Бананка Duo-5000294:_189гр*1шт=189гр ,Рюкзак Urban-5000290:_519гр*1шт=519гр ,Рюкзак Urban-5000289:_519гр*1шт=519гр ,Рюкзак Urban-5000287:_519гр*3шт=1557гр ,Рюкзак Urban-5000286:_519гр*3шт=1557гр ,Рюкзак Gum-5000284:_549гр*3шт=1647гр ,Бананка Town-5000280:_189гр*2шт=378гр ,Итого: 6555гр";

$str = str_replace(',', ',<br>', $str);

echo $str;
```